# How we can do the integration testing of a substrate project?

Tags: pallet, testing

How we can do the integration testing of the substrate application?

Comment: i was doing integration tests like this https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/node/tree/master/runtime/tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few tool which might be useful,

- [subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt) - a library to submit extrinsics to a substrate node via RPC. (from its readme)
- XCM emulator to test XCM configurations - [original location](https://github.com/shaunxw/xcm-simulator/tree/master/xcm-emulator), [fork in cumulus](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/2447)
- [parachains-integration-tests](https://github.com/paritytech/parachains-integration-tests/) - define your chains in a config,  describe you test cases in yaml file and run them. Note this tool is at alfa stage, but it works and we using it. You are welcome to help us to improve it.